# Finding the settling time of an oscillatory response

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

I was reading my book on circuit analysis on chapter about RLC response and became curious about how to get an approximate value for the settling time of the response. Particularly this response

[image]

My first approach was to use the upper envelope of the response and equate to 1 percent of its maximum value and find the approximate settling time which turns out to be Ts = 2.30s.

[image]

Now my question is if there's other method that I can use to better approximate the settling time. My book speaks about a trial-and-error solution but did not show how it's done. Please tell me how to go about it. TIA!

[image]

Comment: What do you think will happen for very large times t ?

Comment: What is the input? What is the desired output? What is the desired settling time tolerance?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to *define* what you mean by settling time. Then the method for finding it will then be as simple, or as difficult, as the definition implies.

The two main definitions are:

a) The last time that the signal passes through some threshold

b) The time that the theoretical envelope of the signal passes through that threshold

With (b), you only have to solve for the decaying envelope, as you've done in your OP.

With (a), you need to take account of the detailed oscillatory behaviour of the output, which involves finding a few candidate cycles around the time that (b) gives the answer, and tracing through which one contains the actual time.

While computing (a) might be an interesting mathematical exercise, there can't be many practical applications that really need anything better than (b).

Comment: I think (b) is commonly known as the "rise time"?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the output by taking the natural log of the exponent. If you realize that the exponent is the same as the 1st order decay time of \$t/\tau\$ . You may define settling time in any way that suits the application or system specs.

The setting time can also be understood by either integer multiples such as 1T, 5T, 8T etc  or fixed ratios of residual voltage of 10%, 5%, 1% ,0.1% or whatever your error budget allows if being used in feedback loop such as a servo.

e^(-2*2.92) = 0.3%. I can only guess why they picked this trial and error criteria.

There is nothing wrong with your choice.